# Finding the number of X11 screens from Haskell

Tags: configuration, haskell, x11, xmonad

I'd like to know how many X screens the current machine has, to make my .xmonad a little more general; I have a netbook as well as a desktop with two monitors, and I use several single monitored machines too.

To this end, I'd like to be able to find out how many X screens the current machine has. (I think screens is the correct words, I mean physical monitors).

The reason being is that I want multiple instances of xmobar, one per monitor. I've hard coded it to be on two at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [the X11 package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/X11/1.5.0.0/doc/html/Graphics-X11-Xinerama.html#v%3agetScreenInfo):

```
 import Graphics.X11.Xinerama (getScreenInfo)
```

that will dynamically return a list of `Rectangle`s, telling you how many screens, and their dimensions.

Comment: How do I get the Display to use as a parameter?

Comment: In the case of xmonad, `display` is part of the `XConf` state, so use e.g. `withDisplay` from `XMonad.Core`.

Answer (score 0):

For the curious, I ended up using

```
 screenCount :: X Int  
 screenCount = withDisplay (io.fmap length.getScreenInfo)
```

I also found out that the XMonad module has a function

```
 screenCount :: Display -> Foreign.C.Types.CInt
```