# XMobar is dying due to a problem in my Xmonad config, related to IO

Tags: haskell, configuration, xmonad

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5607326/215924).
In pursuit of trying to find how many physical monitors I had, I came up with

```
screenCount :: X Int
screenCount = withDisplay (io.fmap length.getScreenInfo)


makeXMobars :: X [Handle] -- loads two xmobars per screen, one top & one bottom
makeXMobars = screenCount >>= (io.mapM spawnPipe.commandHandles )
  where
    commandHandles n = map ((\x -> "xmobar -x " ++ x).unwords) $ commandNames n
    commandNames n = sequence [map show [0..n], map (\x -> "~/.xmobarrc" ++ x) ["Top", "Bottom"]]



myLogHook :: X ()
myLogHook  = do
  handles <- makeXMobars
  dynamicLogWithPP $ defaultPP                                                                   
    {
      ppOutput  = \x -> mapM_ (`hPutStrLn` x) handles
    }
```

myLogHook just drops in to the `xmonad $ DefaultConfig`. However, when I load XMonad the PipeReader for the top XMobars (on both screens) just shows `updating` for a little while, and then disappears, and refuses to come back when I reload. The bottom ones are perfectly happy.

Previously, I simply used for my ppOutput:

```
 ppOutput = \x -> hPutStrLn xmobarTopScreen0 x >> hPutStrLn xmobarTopScreen1 x
```

which worked perfectly fine.

I assume I've made some error with my understanding of IO, rather than the code itself being bad per se, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you want to use `map show [0 .. n-1]` rather than `map show [0 .. n]`. I also suggest that you spawn the xmobar instances in `main` rather than in `logHook`, since the latter will spawn brand new copies of xmobar every time you do any xmonad action (like changing focus). As for `screenCount`, may I suggest [countScreens](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html#v%3AcountScreens) from the `IndependentScreens` module?