# How to put an instance of XMobar on each screen in XMonad?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

I'm running XMonad on a laptop that I sometimes, but not always, have an additional monitor attached. I'd like to detect the number of screens in my `xmonad.hs` have a instance of XMobar per screen.

I've seen [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607326/finding-the-number-of-x11-screens-from-haskell), but I've not really got my head around monad transformers and how to make use of a value of type `X [Rectangle]`.

Right now, I have, roughly, this:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
import XMonad.Util.Run(spawnPipe)
import XMonad.Core (X ,withDisplay ,io)
import Graphics.X11.Xinerama (getScreenInfo)
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types (Rectangle)
import System.IO

xdisplays :: X [Rectangle]
xdisplays = withDisplay $ io . getScreenInfo

main = do
    xmproc <- spawnPipe "/usr/bin/xmobar /home/liam/.xmobarrc"
    xmonad $ desktopConfig
        { layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig,
          manageHook = manageHook defaultConfig <+> manageDocks,
          logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
            { ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
            }
        }
```

Naively, I'd like to put `rects <- xdisplays` at the start of my do block, then spawn xmobar instances appropriately, but obviously this doesn't work because the type is `X [Rectangle]` not `IO [Rectangle]`. I wondered if I need to use [runX](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:runX) somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`startupHook`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:startupHook) to run an `X` action on every invocation of xmonad. For example,

```
main = xmonad $ desktopConfig
    { startupHook = do
        rects <- xdisplays
        {- spawn xmobar -}
    }
```

You might also like [`countScreens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-IndependentScreens.html#v:countScreens) if all you actually care about is how many screens there are and [`spawnOnce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Util-SpawnOnce.html) so that you don't get an extra copy of xmobar on each restart of xmonad.