# How to spawn XMobar instance for each screen?

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46736192/how-to-put-an-instance-of-xmobar-on-each-screen-in-xmonad) has an appropriate answer, but it's hiding everything I found difficult inside "spawn xmobar" comment.
- How to spawn one instance of xmobar for different screens?
- If this is not an option, how to spawn multiple instances on multiple screens?
- How to setup logHook with multiple instances of xmobar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

e.g. something like this:

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Util.Run
import XMonad.Layout.IndependentScreens

main = do
    n <- countScreens
    xmprocs <- mapM (\i -> spawnPipe $ "xmobar /home/biskulopty/.xmobarrc-" ++ show i ++ " -x " ++ show i) [0..n-1]
    xmonad def {
        logHook = {- use xmprocs, which is a list of pipes of type [Handle] -}
    }
```

Comment: Great, I got it working like this:  
`mapM_ (\handle -> dynamicLogWithPP $ defaultPP { ppOutput = System.IO.hPutStrLn handle }) xmprocs
`