# Use Xmobar on several Monitors

Tags: haskell, window-managers, xmonad, xmobar

This Question was answered several times but I do not understand the accepted answers. For example here [How to spawn XMobar instance for each screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876381/how-to-spawn-xmobar-instance-for-each-screen). In the question the user refers to another question where the solution is hidden behind a comment. But the accepted answer in this thread still hides code behind a comment. Can someone post a xmonad.hs that solves the problem and can be compiled?

I also asked this question here https://www.reddit.com/r/xmonad/comments/lowbw1/same_xmobar_on_several_screens/ but got the answer that it is not possible. But as written above there seems to be a solution since there were accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using Xmonad as your window manager, you can spawn xmobar in your xmonad.hs this way, importing [XMonad.Util.Run](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Util-Run.html) to run 'spawnPipe'

```
main = do
     -- Launching three instances of xmobar on their monitors.
     xmproc0 <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 0 $HOME/.config/xmobar/xmobarrc0"
     xmproc1 <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 1 $HOME/.config/xmobar/xmobarrc2"
     xmproc2 <- spawnPipe "xmobar -x 2 $HOME/.config/xmobar/xmobarrc1"
```

it can be the same xmobarrc if you want.

With this you can pass parameters from Xmonad, like your workspaces, layouts, etc, to xmobar, defining in your def config

```
xmonad $ def {
      keys = myKeys
    , otherHooks...
    , logHook = myLogHook <+> dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
                    { ppOutput = \x -> hPutStrLn xmproc0 x  >> hPutStrLn xmproc1 x  >> hPutStrLn xmproc2 x
    , ppFormats
    }
}
```

for the ppFormats check [XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html)

And, if you aren't using Xmonad, probably defining in your startup file like .xinitrc or the file you use adding

```
exec 'xmobar -x 0 /path/to/config' &
exec 'xmobar -x 1 /path/to/config' &
exec ...
```

would work fine, but this I can't tell you how to pass info of you windows to xmobar.

I found this code [here](https://gitlab.com/dwt1/dotfiles), there you can find an amazingly long xmonad config to take notes and ideas, and also some xmobar configs.

Hope this was helpfull